# Yii2 валидация файла

Tags: yii, валидация

Ребята!
Не отображается сообщение о валидации формата файла. Я пишу.

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['image'], 'required', 'message'=>'Загрузите картинку'],
            [['image'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'jpg, png', 'message'=>'Только форматы jpg и png']
        ];
    }
```

Кто-нибудь знает, как вместо Only files with these extensions are allowed: jpg, png. вывести свое сообщение?

Answer (score 0):

Хм, попробуйте **wrongExtension** вместо **message**:

```
public function rules()
{
        return [
            [['image'], 'required', 'message'=>'Загрузите картинку'],
            [['image'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'jpg, png', 'wrongExtension'=>'Только форматы jpg и png']
        ];
}
```

И вот [силка](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator) на документацию поданному валидатору со всеми возможными сообщениями.

Также если вам нужно выводить валидацию на рус. тогда проще будет изменить язык фреймворка в файле конфига, так как с коробки yii2 поддерживает 3 языка ru, ua, en